# content organizer rules using properties

Tags: content, content-organizer-rule

I want to set up a rule to route SP form library forms sent to the dropoff library.
Though the content type of the form is selectable when setting the rule, the promoted fields are not selectable as properties to meet the required condition.
The only selectable values are content type and name.
I already found the Information that the column to be selected has to be displayed which i already checked.

Is there any other requirement which has to be met before a column shows up?

Thank you.